# Calculating time between high state

Tags: python, signal-processing

In python I want calculations of high / low states of a signal in chunks of a given size (`samples_to_process`).

The two required calculations are number index between rising edges (`length_between_high_states`) and number of index's the signal is high for (`high_state_length`).

The calculations must be stateful across chunnks.

[image: example]

Lets take a small reproduceable example:

```
data = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0])
```

If this array is read 8 items at a time, the first iteration is

```
high_state_length = 2 
length_between_high_states = 3
```

then

```
high_state_length = 3
length_between_high_states = 9
```

I believe I have the correct logic to read in the first state of the array and signal changes, but subsequent state changes in the signal and carrying the state across chunks are not yet implemented:

```
import numpy as np
#total array size = 25
data = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0])
#size of samples of data array to process in each read
samples_to_process = 8
samples = np.zeros(samples_to_process, dtype=np.complex64)
threshold = 0.5

index = 0
#slice(index, index+samples_to_process)
for index in range(0, data.size, samples_to_process):
    samples=data[index:index+samples_to_process]
    print(samples)
    while True
        start_index = np.argmax(samples > threshold)
        stop_index = np.argmax(samples[start_index:] < threshold) + start_index
        next_start_index = np.argmax(samples[stop_index:] > threshold) + stop_index
        length_between_high_states = next_start_index - start_index
        high_state_length = stop_index - start_index
        # how to calculate remainder state and pass into next itr
        start_index = next_start_index
        print("next loop")
```

The question is how to pass the signal state between iterations to be included in subsequent calculations.

Comment: Its hard to understand what is your exact problem. First, I propose use different word than "sample" as you already have samples and sampling frequency. Chunk = sample? Secoond thing, if you want your code to work continuously, you need to keep some info in memory: time of last "high", also last sample (meaning last point..), etc.

Comment: Also, I would consider thresholding your input once, at the start, rather than thresholding twice for every peak - once for rising edge and then again for falling edge.

Comment: Yes original question was hard to follow. Try this minimum, repeatable example.

Comment: Consider it this way.  Go through the signal sample by sample.  When you get a 0-to-1 transition, remember the time.  Then, when you get a 1-to-0 transition, you know the length of the last high state.  When you get another 0-to-1 transition, you can compute the time since the last 0-to-1, and start again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to track the last rising edge, and the state of the last sample.  Then, you get an event on each rising edge and each falling edge.

(I've now reworked this to use a class to maintain the state data.)

```
import numpy as np
#total array size = 25
data = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0])
#size of samples of data array to process in each read
samples_to_process = 8
threshold = 0.5

def islow(v):
    return v < threshold
def ishigh(v):
    return v >= threshold

class Checker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last = 0
        self.lastrise = 0
        self.index = 0

    def feed(self, samples):
        for j,n in enumerate(samples):
            i = self.index + j
            # Is this a rising edge?
            if ishigh(n) and islow(self.last):
                if self.lastrise:
                    print('since last rising edge:', i-self.lastrise)
                self.lastrise = i
            # Is this a falling edge?
            elif islow(n) and ishigh(self.last):
                print('pulse width', i-self.lastrise)
            self.last = n
        self.index += len(samples)

checker = Checker()
for index in range(0, data.size, samples_to_process):
    checker.feed( data[index:index+samples_to_process] )
```

Output:

```
pulse width 2
since last rising edge: 3
pulse width 2
since last rising edge: 8
pulse width 6
since last rising edge: 13
pulse width 3
since last rising edge: 7
pulse width 4
```

### Followup

Really, like most algorithms, this is just doing what you would do on paper.  `last` holds the previous signal level.  `lastrise` holds the index of the last rising edge (0-to-1 transition)

You asked about this statement:

```
for j,n in enumerate(samples):
```

The `enumerate` function is a better way to handle running through a list of things when you need the index of the item as well.  It is functionally identical to:

```
for j in range(len(samples)):
    n = samples[j]
```

except that it is more efficient.  I need to have the index of the sample so I can compute the current position in the chunk.  So, within that loop, `j` has the index of the current sample, and `n` has the level of the sample.

Comment: Any chance of slightly more verbose comments? Still getting my head around the answer. Especially around j and n :-)

Comment: Thanks @Tim Roberts. Would it be allowed to tweak the question?

Comment: I over simplified the Q. The numbers are between 0.1 0.2 if low, and above 0.5 if high. Also the data array is often in the order of a few million, hence I was using numpy and argmax. If allowed will tweak Q.

Comment: Then create functions `islow` and `ishigh`, and change the comparisons to `if ishigh(n) and islow(last)`.

Comment: Nice. I will test this out and see what performance is like. Thanks for the update.

Comment: What you wrote @Tim works perfectly. I have realised however I still have removed too much detail...`data` is a stream read into samples - so data is no longer an array. This affects the way lastrise is used to calcualte gap when used between rises in different samples. Can I tweak the Question?

Comment: It makes no difference.  The outer loop in your example is already simulating getting the signal as a set of smaller segments.  As long as you maintain `last`, `lastrise`, and `index` as globals. it all works just fine.  You might consider making it a class, so that those variables are part of the object state.  You can call `checker.feed(...)` to feed in the next chunk of data.

Comment: But `for index in range(0, data.size, samples_to_process):` doesnt exist because the data is coming from a stream

Comment: Right.  You would replace that with something that keeps track of the current index.  That's all.  Use your imagination...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256163/discussion-between-al-grant-and-tim-roberts).

Comment: But the stream doesnt have a index, the only index now relates to the `current sample` vs `data` which doesnt exist when used with a stream

Comment: Yes, but all that means is that you have to keep TRACK of the index.  Start at 0, update it every time you get another batch of samples.  Did you notice I modified my answer to do exactly that?

Comment: Right, but the stream could run for years at 2.4M samples/sec - the index will get very very very big if carried over.

Comment: (1) Nobody actually has an application that runs for years without restarting.  (2) Python integers can be arbitrarily large.  (3) You can handle this by setting `lastrise` negative (`lastrise -= len(samples)` and starting `index` at 0 each time.  You're not THINKING about your problems.

Comment: Ok, but the calcualtion only wants to be performed using `handle this by setting lastrise negative (lastrise -= len(samples)` if lastrise is in a different set of samples - otherwise its just `i-lastrise`

Comment: Not at all.  If lastrise is -9, that means the last rising edge was 9 samples before the start of the current set.

Comment: Sometimes there could be two pulses in the same sample, other times there will be pulses in seperate samples. Same sample `i-lastrise` but if lastrise becomes a negative number then I have `i-(-lastrise)` which results in addition?

Comment: That's exactly right.  If the last rising edge was 5 samples before the end of the last chunk, then lastrise == -5.  If the next rising edge happens at i=3, then the time since the last right is (3 - -5) or 8.  I feel like you'd be a lot better off by just trying this code and monitoring the values while it runs.  It DOES work.